# JSF Quartz 2.x integration without xml file

Tags: java, jsf-2, quartz-scheduler

i need a quartz job in my project. but i need to give the scheduler like this in any class

```
JobDetail jd=new JobDetail(“myjob”,sched.DEFAULT_GROUP,HelloJob.class);
SimpleTrigger st=new SimpleTrigger(“mytrigger”,sched.DEFAULT_GROUP,new Date(),
null,SimpleTrigger.REPEAT_INDEFINITELY,60L*1000L);
sched.scheduleJob(jd, st);
```

i don want to user quartz-config.xml. how can use the quartz scheuler in JSF without xml trigger ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [DirectSchedulerFactory](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.1.0/org/quartz/impl/DirectSchedulerFactory.html) and create a scheduler thereby with any of its createScheduler method. You will configure quartz without any quartz config file here .